# How to delete a messageEmbed after 9 seconds. [BOT Discord]

Tags: discord, discord.js

With my Discord bot, I would like to delete a message the client sent after 9 seconds. I have already tried with `message.delete([1000])`, but this deletes the message sent by the *user*.

This is my current attempt:

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
    color: 15488557,
    title: '❌ Problème dans la commande.',
}});

message.delete([10000])
```

Comment: It's the surrounded message who is delete, not the message send by the bot ( Develop. by EЯЯОЯ
https://i.imgur.com/Ib8ms5P.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `message.delete()` this means: delete **user** message not **client(bot)** message. You need to do `.then(m => m.delete())`, good luck!

```js
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setTitle('❌ Problème dans la commande.')
 .setColor('#hexcode')
message.channel.sendEmbed(embed)
.then(msg => msg.delete(9000)).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: `.sendEmbed()` is deprecated! You can use `.send()` for every kind of message.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's this. You save me ^^. Thank you thank you 
I had need to this method and the other method below. You are a genius ! ^^. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

`TextBasedChannel.send()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolving with the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) sent. That means that in your case, you can attach a [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method to use the returned value.

```js
message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    color: 15488557,
    title: '❌ Problème dans la commande.',
  }
})
  .then(reply => reply.delete(9000))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's this. You save me ^^. Thank you thank you 
I had need to this method and the other method above. You are a genius ! ^^. Thank you so much.